# geom_scatterpie with a legend that is unscaled

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterpie

I would like to have the radius of my piecharts scaled by sample size (`n`) on a map. However, the variance in `n` is large, so I would like rescale it on the map, say from 0 to 1 (this could be a log, or anything really). I would like the legend to show the scaled sizes, but give the actual values of n, not the scales.

So, in the example below, the legend would show circles of widths 0 to 1, but with each tick mark on the circles labelled 0 through 500. Thus the viewer would understand that the circles are scaled, but could get a sense of the actual sample size, not just the relative, scaled sample size.

For example:

```
library(ggplot)
library(scatterpie)

df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                 lat = c(30, 31, 32), 
                 long = c(-85, -86, -87),
                 a = c(1, 3, 5),
                 b = c(8, 7, 4),
                 c = c(1, 0, 1),
                 n = c(1, 200, 500))

# Plotting without scaling yields pies that will not fit on a map (the axes are too large)
ggplot()+
  geom_scatterpie(data = df,
                  aes(y = lat, x = long,
                      group = id,
                      r = n),
                      cols = c("a", "b", "c"))+
  geom_scatterpie_legend(df$n, x = -85.5, y = 32.5)

# Plotting the rescaled size is also a bit big, but importantly shows the scaled values in the legend

# Rescale n to 0 to 1
df$r <- scales::rescale(df$n, to = c(0, 1))

ggplot()+
  geom_scatterpie(data = df,
                  aes(y = lat, x = long,
                      group = id,
                      r = r),
                  cols = c("a", "b", "c"))+
  geom_scatterpie_legend(df$r, x = -85.5, y = 32.5)
```

Is there a better way to rescale in `geom_scatterpie` so 1) scales with large variance allow all pies to be visible, and 2) the legend shows the actual values, not the scaled values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually rescale by simply dividing the count by the maximum count inside `aes`. This is reversed inside `geom_scatterpie_legend` using the `labeller` argument:

```r
ggplot()+
  geom_scatterpie(data = df,
                  aes(y = lat, x = long,
                      group = id,
                      r = n / max(n)),
                  cols = c("a", "b", "c")) +
  geom_scatterpie_legend(df$n/max(df$n), labeller = function(x) x * max(df$n),
                         x = -84.5, y = 31) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds like I need to rephrase my question. This does solve the scaling issue, but the scale itself is still wonky. If this were to be plotted on a map, the left-most pie would take up two degrees of latitude. That seems unreasonable for the extent of the plot. What would a better scalar be other than `x / max(x)`?

Comment: @AlexKrohn I thought you _wanted_ it that large. The size of the legend is relative to the scale of your x and y axes. So if you want the radius of the biggest circle to be one-quarter of a degree rather than one degree, you need to ensure that the maximum value of the `r` aesthetic is 0.25. You can do this by setting it to `0.25 * n / max(n)` and the first argument of `geom_scatterpie_legend` to `0.25 * df$n / max(df$n)`. Remember to also change your `labeller` to `function(x) 4 * x * max(df$n)`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! `geom_scatterpie` could have so much better documentation. I'm glad someone figured this out...